# Total metamask balance

Tags: metamask, balances, hd-wallets

I am curious how to get the **total** current balance of my metamask wallet with as many "accounts" inside it as it bears in the moment?

As I can understand metamask is the HD wallet and all my addresses in it are derived from my seed phrase and xpub/private key.

So is it possible to find a service or (preferably) to write a script to calculate total balance of my metamask wallet using my xpub or another root info? Please show me the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can get the balance of a single account via:**

```
web3.eth.getBalance(address);
```

**By default you will get all accounts of metamask.** *(this code uses await and therefore has to be placed within an async function)*

```
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
```

**What you get is an array with all the accounts.** Now it is up to you to loop through them and sum up the balance.